# Some websites block XPATH reading from SELENIUM

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

This is the code i was doing from the beggining, the error i found in this is 'selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="v1bodyTable"]"}', exactly the same type as in the youtube-facebook problem, i have no ideia what to do

```html
import time

import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.maximize_window() # For maximizing window
driver.implicitly_wait(20) # gives an implicit wait for 20 seconds
driver.get("https://cpanel13.dnscpanel.com:2096/cpsess6746706896/3rdparty/roundcube/?_task=mail&_mbox=INBOX")
driver.find_element(By.ID,"user").send_keys("geral@belleville.pt")
driver.find_element(By.ID,"pass").send_keys("xxxxxxx")
act=ActionChains(driver)
act.key_down(Keys.ENTER).perform()



link = driver.find_elements(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Temos um interessado no seu anúncio no Imovirtual")
if link != None:
    while link != None:
        try:
            link = driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Temos um interessado no seu anúncio no Imovirtual").click()
            act.key_down(Keys.DELETE).perform()
            link = driver.find_elements(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Temos um interessado no seu anúncio no Imovirtual")
        except NoSuchElementException :
            break


link2 = driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "sobre o teu imóvel, com a ref")
link2.click()
nome = driver.find_element(By.ID, "v1bodyTable").text
time.sleep(3)
print = nome


while True:
    pass
```

`I am new to Selenium and I've spent the last days trying to copy and paste information between websites. The biggest problem I've faced is that sometimes I try to find a text, a button, ... through XPATH the program runs until it fails saying element not found. The following code shows a simple example where I can't click on the` allow cookies`on Facebook. I've tried`time.sleep()`, checking the XPATH, and using other attributes like ID, but nothing seems to work.

```py
import time

import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.maximize_window() # For maximizing window
driver.implicitly_wait(20) # gives an implicit wait for 20 seconds
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "ACEITAR TUDO").click()
yomomass = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="text"]').text
time.sleep(3)
print(yomomass)
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="u_0_e_K6"]').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "email").send_keys("yomomass")

while True:
    pass
```

Comment: `[@id="u_0_e_K6"]` I'm just guessing, but that looks like a randomly-generated id.  If I'm right, you can't count on it remaining the same from one page load to the next.

Comment: Also, if you know the element id, why are you bothering with xpath at all?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer! I'm trying to copy and past information between 2 websites, but i ran into this problem. To see if the problem was with the websites, i tried to do this with facebook and youtube, well known websites. But either with ID (By.ID, "vi1bodyTable") or XPATH (By. XPATH, '//*[@id="v1bodyTable"]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/span') the program after some time, just shuts down saying  selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="v1bodyTable"]"}.

Comment: Hi, i've checked in the original code, which searches information in emails, and the thing i am looking for isn't randomly-generated, the ID, and so the XPATH are always the same (XPATH - //*[@id="v1bodyTable"]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/span)

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a User-Agent option to your webdriver, I've found that it solves this problem with some websites

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options) #add ur other argument
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i am a real newbie when it comes to this. What is a User-Agent option, and how can i implement it on my code, since i cant simply copy and past what you've wrote. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah,  so I think you can do everything I wrote but when you are creating the driver, do `driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())`. And the user agent "spoofs" what kind of user is accessing the website. Some sites can detect that selenium is using javascript for automation, so they block it, but the user agent helps bypass that